# Is it legal for a Company to discuss your application with and outside Agency?

Tags: applications

I applied for a position (#1) with a company directly, and later for a different position (#2) via an agency.

When I contacted the agency for updates on my application for role #2, I was told that the company had informed them that I had applied for role #1.

The agency is looking at whether this is an issue for them, but my stance is that my other application is none of their business because:

1. I applied before the Agency contacted me with a second role.
2. I applied directly on the Company's website.

Should my application information not be confidential?

Comment: We don't really give legal advice here. If it's an easy question that any HR manager should be able to answer we can help, but that would require a location so that we know _where_ it is/is not legal.

Comment: Also, you numbered 3 things but I think only the last one is the actual question you want answered, right?

Comment: What do you mean "legal" at most it would be unprofessional and counter to the companies interests why pay a recruiter when the could have just forward your cv to the appropriate department and save money.

Comment: I think this incident tells you a little something both about this employer, and the recruitment agency. I would avoid both.

Comment: Why do you suspect it may not be legal? How did you come to expect that your application should be confidential?

Comment: This is the reason I don't use a recruitment agency.  Despite what they might claim they never are there to help you.

Answer (score 2):

The company is simply telling the Agency "We already knew about Ave65, so you don't get a finders fee."

The Agency only gets paid for "unknown applicants", regardless of the position. Usually agencies first ask the applicant have you already applied to the company before submitting for this reason.

I'm not a lawyer, but I don't see any reason why this would be illegal, unless you had some agreement such as an NDA.

Comment: What about data protection?  Surely the fact I had applied for the other job is irrelevant.  If it was the same job it might be okay

Comment: @Ave65 depends upon your jurisdiction but I can't see there being any data protection concerns here.

Comment: @Ave65 I'm telling you its NOT irrelevant. The agency contract with the employer says that if you applied for any position in the past X days they don't get a finders fee. Also if they submit you (when you did not already apply), and the company hires you, the agency get the finders fee regardless of  what position they hire you for.

Comment: Well I guess my concern is that my application to the company was direct to them and in no way connected to the Agency - so is it right that the company disclosed this to the agency?  Surely that's between then and me - particularly now as the agency said it might affect the application they put forward on my behalf.

Comment: Sorry, just read your second comment.  So to be clear - I applied direct BEFORE the agency contacted me about the other role (a different one).

Comment: @Ave65 The Agency is not entitled to commission for finding you, the company has to tell them why. ie the Company has to tell the agency "Ave65 already applied (for some other position) so you are not eligible for a finders fee" . How else can they say this without disclosing that you already applied?

Comment: Oh okay. Guess I need to withdraw the agency application then.  Thanks - much appreciated.